# Splitting field of $X^3-5$ and over $\Bbb{F}_p$, $p=7,11,13$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, splitting-field

Please help me to find the splitting field of $X^3-5$  over $\Bbb{F}_p$, $p=7,11,13$.

Thanks,

Comment: It would be better to include attempts. For instance, have you checked if there are any roots of $x^3-5$ in $\mathbb{F}_7,\mathbb{F}_{11},\mathbb{F}_{13}$? There has to be one in $\mathbb{F}_{11}$, since the map $x\mapsto x^3$ is surjective there.

Comment: Yes ther is a root in $F_{11}$ is 3, but i have another polynome of degree 2. How to find her splitting field? Thanks

Comment: A quadratic polynomial either factors completely or is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p$, according to its discriminant being or not a quadratic residue $\pmod{p}$.

Comment: As an alternative, since $x\mapsto x^3$ is bijective over $\mathbb{F}_{11}$, $x^3-5$ only has one root in $\mathbb{F}_{11}$, so its splitting field is $\mathbb{F}_{11^2}$ (i.e. the quadratic factor is irreducible).

Comment: Over $\mathbb{F}_7^*$ and $\mathbb{F}_{13}^*$ the map $x\mapsto x^3$ is $3$-to-$1$ (since $7$ and $13$ are primes of the form $3k+1$). So if $5$ is a cubic residue the polynomial factors completely, otherwise it is irreducible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a third degree polynomial hasn’t root on his field of definition it is irreducible.

Seeing $f(x)=x^3-5\in\mathbb{F}_7[x]$ you can see by counting that $\nexists y\in\mathbb{F}_7$ so that $y^3\equiv 5 \bmod7$ so the polinomial is irreducible and his split field is $\mathbb{F}_{7^3}$.

Instead in $\mathbb{F}_{11}$ $3$ is a root of $f(x)$, so you have $x^3-5=x^3-3^3=(x-3)(x^2+3x+9)$ where the quadratic has discriminant $\Delta =-27=6$ then it is reducible iff $6$ is a perfect square in $\mathbb{F}_{11}$ and by counting you see it is no possible. So the split field of $f(x)\in \mathbb{F}_{11}[x]$ is $\mathbb{F}_{11^2}$

Seeing $f(x)\in \mathbb{F}_{13}[x]$ we have that $2^3=\equiv -5\, \bmod13\iff (-2)^3\equiv 11^3\equiv 5\, \bmod13$. So we have that $11$ is root of $f(x)$ and $x^3-5=(x-11)(x^2+11x+121)=(x-11)(x^2+11x+4)$ where the quadratic has discriminant $\Delta =121-16=105=1$ so it is reducible and $f(x)$ is completely splittable on $\mathbb{F}_{13}$.

Answer (score 1):

The polynomial $x^3-5$ doesn't have a root in $\Bbb F_7$, so is irreducible.   Hence the splitting field is $\Bbb F_{7^3}$.

Over $\Bbb F_{13}$, we have a root ($11\cong -2$).  Thus, using @Jack D'Aurizio's comments,  the polynomial splits.